# How much time -depending on dumbell size

Tags: programs, biceps, growth

I would like to know if 5kg dumbbell is enough to grow "big" biceps. Of course ,I know more kg can give faster results, but because I now re-start my workouts.I would like to start slow.I want to start doing 5kg (which is not much kg) to make a visible biceps.

Can that be possible?

I am doing it at night 100 per hand of 5 kg.  (**Every night!**)

Is something better I can do for my biceps with 5kg?

The next month, I will go from 5 to 10 kg.

I don't want advice on how to build biceps with different ways - because I haven't right now anything.
I want with 5kg to know how much time per day and how many sets I should be doing.
One example I am doing 5kg 1 set each hand by 100.
If I  am doing 2 set it will be 200 per hand.
I have heard that daily is not good to do "biceps",but because the "weights" are not much, at my view I can do.
Any idea on that issue?

Comment: I think you should read this answer. https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/36236/31261 It includes rep ranges that are ideal for hypertrophy. You simply do not want to be working out that light if you can do 100+ reps in one set. You want to be within 1-2 reps of failure after 6-12 reps for hypertrophy. If you aren't near that range, you are working out with improper weight if you want to maximize muscle growth. A few side notes, working the same muscle every night is bad. Let it rest 48 hours between. Also, diet and sleep are more important than the workout.

Comment: Another relevant question: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/43133/when-do-repetitions-stop-being-heavy/43147

Comment: @EricWarburton thanks for the response ,my english are not so good but if I got it right you mean that I must do 1 or 2 reps of 100 each hand (it mustn't be 5kg-it must be more kg so it will be hard to lift ) and after I must do 6 reps of 100 until 12 reps .somewhere between there..

Comment: or   you mean that ,I must do lets say with 25kg 1 -2 reps and after to take 15 kg for 6-12 reps? I didn't got it because my enlgish are not good to get it. I get in the answer to but the pdf is missing.The answers are based on their example.Because I wrote  a different case I don't know if you answer on that or not .

Comment: What I am saying is that you need to lift more than 5kg. Find a weight such as 10-15 kg where you can only lift it 6-12 times per arm. As you get stronger, you will need to increase the weight even more. David is correct, current research says there is a larger hypertrophic range than just 6-12. I gave you that range because it is important that you know you must use heavier weights. As his answer states you really shouldn't be able to do 30+ reps or you are missing out on muscle gains. It is a solid answer that you should read as well.

Comment: thank you.   I didn't get the meaning before .Now your comment was helpful for me to get it .I got it.I am greatful for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips here, if you are wanting to stay at 5kg or use more reps and build bigger biceps:

- muscles need 48 hours to recover from a workout. stick to 3 times a week. I know it seems counter productive but if you do more, you will actually make your biceps stop growing, or even get smaller! Once a day!
- Slow down and do 2 seconds to lift the weight, and 2 seconds to lower the weight, then flex your bicep when you are at top of movement. I guarantee you 4-5 seconds per rep will quickly prevent you from getting 100 reps.
- Try supersetting with other moves.. do a drag curl, reverse curl, zottman curl, preacher curl, concentration curl and do 2 or 3 exercises back to back.
- Try different exercises.. 5kg is a fair weight and 100 reps seems too much even for 5kg... so try 1 or 2 exercises a day, 3 times a week and rotate throughout the week. choose from the list above or look up moves. you can focus on the short head or long head of the bicep, or focus on both. again dont overtrain or do too many exercises.
- if you're doing alternating db curls, stop. do regular curls.
- century sets. Try to pick a weight that you can do 27-40 reps with. subtract that from 100.  rest 1 second for however many reps you couldnt finish. then do as many as possible reps. subtract the total from 100 again and rest 1 second for each rep not finished. repeat until complete.
- focus on form, slow down, keep elbow by sides, squeeze biceps at top of movement.
- hypertrophy is roughly 8-12 reps, strength is 4-8, power is 1-3, 12-20 is endurance, 20+ is lactic.. with the exception of century sets, doing an extreme amount of reps will just build lactic acid, and after 50 it becomes cardio.. you should really slow down, focus on form, and increase weight, and pick different exercises.

Answer (score -3):

Higher repetitions increases the endurance. It will give you the beautiful biceps shape but to increase size of the biceps you will have to progressively increase the weight.

For now if you want to utilize the 5 kg dumbbells to the maximum, do it as you are doing: 100 or more. Why do less when you can do more? If however you want to increase the challenge, try super sets of chins and curls. Sometimes you can try supersets of push ups and curls. If you still are not satisfied, try tri-sets of chins, push ups and curls.

No less. And no other fancy ways: 15 sets of 6, 10 sets of 10, 3 sets 4 times a day, and so forth. Don't do those. No.